# Error building bitstring in python 3.5 : the datatype is being set to U32 without my control

Tags: python, string, numpy, type-conversion

I'm using a function to build an array of strings (which happens to be 0s and 1s only), which are rather large. The function works when I am building smaller strings, but somehow the data type seems to be restricting the size of the string to 32 characters long (U32), without my having asked for it. Am I missing something simple?

As I build the strings, I am first casting them as lists so as to more easily manipulate individual characters before joining them into a string again. Am I somehow limiting my ability to use 'larger' data types by my method?  The value of np.max(CM1) in this case is something like ~300 (one recent run yielded 253), but the string only come out 32 characters long...

```
''' Function to derive genome and count mutations in provided list of cells ''' 
def derive_genome_biopsy(biopsy_list, family_dict, CM1):
    derived_genomes_inBx = np.zeros(len(biopsy_list)).astype(str)
    for position, cell in np.ndenumerate(biopsy_list):
        if cell == 0: continue
        temp_parent = 2
        bitstring = list('1')
        bitstring += (np.max(CM1)-1)*'0'
        if cell == 1:
            derived_genomes_inBx[position] = ''.join(bitstring)
            continue 
        else:
            while temp_parent > 1:
                temp_parent = family_dict[cell]
                bitstring[cell-1] = '1'
                if temp_parent == 1: break
                cell = family_dict[cell]
            derived_genomes_inBx[position] = ''.join(bitstring)
    return derived_genomes_inBx
```

The specific error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "biopsyCA.py", line 77, in <module>
    if genome[site] == '1': 
IndexError: string index out of range
```

family_dict is a dictionary which carries a list of parents and children that the algorithm above works through to reconstruct the 'genome' of individuals from the branching family tree. it basically sets positions in the bitstring to '1' if your parent had it, then if your grandparent etc... until you get to the first bit, which is always '1', then it should be done.

Comment: You will increase the change to get a good answer if you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your comment.  Important details like that should not be hiding in the comments section.

Comment: Have you tried printing `np.max(CM1) - 1` to be sure it's what you think it is?

Comment: I've edited the question as you suggested Kevin and Mike. Also, I printed np.max(CM1)-1 and got 253. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 32 character limitation comes from the conversion of float64 array to string array in this line:

```
derived_genomes_inBx = np.zeros(len(biopsy_list)).astype(str)
```

The resulting array contains datatype S32 values which limit the contents to 32 characters.

To change this limit, use 'S300' or larger instead of str.

You may also use `map(str, np.zeros(len(biopsy_list))` to get more flexible string list and convert it back to numpy array with `numpy.array()` after you have populated it.

Comment: I used the 'S300' solution and it worked - thanks. However, it induced a new error later on in my code... at a later time, I want to sum all the digits in a given position in each genome, and there is an issue arising trying to manipulate individual member of the bitstring. am I just being silly? also, couldn't the map solution you suggested to work...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Map works like that in Python2, but in Python3 it needs to be `list(map(str, np.zeros(len(biopsy_list)))`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to help from a number of folks here and local, I finally got this working and the working function is:

```
''' Function to derive genome and count mutations in provided list of cells ''' 
def derive_genome_biopsy(biopsy_list, family_dict, CM1):
    derived_genomes_inBx = list(map(str, np.zeros(len(biopsy_list))))
    for biopsy in range(0,len(biopsy_list)):
        if biopsy_list[biopsy] == 0:
            bitstring = (np.max(CM1))*'0'
            derived_genomes_inBx[biopsy] = ''.join(bitstring)
            continue
        bitstring = list('1')
        bitstring += (np.max(CM1)-1)*'0'
        if biopsy_list[biopsy] == 1:
            derived_genomes_inBx[biopsy] = ''.join(bitstring)
            continue 
        else:
            temp_parent = family_dict[biopsy_list[biopsy]]
            bitstring[biopsy_list[biopsy]-1] = '1'
            while temp_parent > 1:
                temp_parent = family_dict[position]
                bitstring[temp_parent-1] = '1'
                if temp_parent == 1: break          
            derived_genomes_inBx[biopsy] = ''.join(bitstring)
    return derived_genomes_inBx
```

The original problem was as Teppo Tammisto pointed out an issue with the 'str' datastructure taking 'S32' format. Once I changed to using the list(map(str, ...) functionality a few more issues arose with the original code, which I've now fixed. When I finish this thesis chapter I'll publish the whole family of functions to use to virtually 'biopsy' a cellular automaton model (well, just an array really) and reconstruct 'genomes' from family tree data and the current automaton state vector.

Thanks all!